# what's the meaning of "\\p{all}" in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am working with some java code, that has the following statement:

```
if (sql1.matches("(?i)^CREATE\\s+TABLE\\p{all}*")) {
     // do something;
}
```

I have searched the regex syntax and can't find a rule that uses `\\p{all}`. So what's the meaning of this expression?

Comment: I can't find the documentation, but It seems `\p{all}` match any character, It seems also that The equivalent of `\p{all}` is `.*`, it is more significant. with `all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unicode `all` category is added "manually" to the list of categories to match any char, including line breaks, etc.

See [Java `regex` source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l5674):

```
map.put("all", new CharPropertyFactory() {
                CharProperty make() { return new All(); }});
```

and then [this part](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l4139):

```
/**
 * Implements the Unicode category ALL and the dot metacharacter when
 * in dotall mode.
 */
static final class All extends CharProperty {
    boolean isSatisfiedBy(int ch) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`All()` is used to instantiate `.` with `DOTALL` mode, see [this part](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l2102):

```
case '.':
    next();
    if (has(DOTALL)) {
        node = new All();
    } ....
```

Answer (score 0):

`\p{all}` in Java is a synonym for general category `\p{Any}` in Perl which means:

> All Unicode codepoints [`\x{0000}-\x{10FFFF}`].

It works as `\X` (Match Unicode "eXtended grapheme cluster") or `(?s:.)` in other flavors.

Below shot is from Mastering Regular Expressions by Jeffrey E.F. Friedl:

[image]

Also an `All` property exists in Perl which has a more including definition:

> All code points, including those above Unicode.